# Customizing JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

Good Day.

If the JLabel and JTextField font size can be changed as desired, is it possible to change also the font style (size, face, color) of the column names and elements of a JTable?

Adding more, I'm using the Look and feel of Windows.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BasicTableHeaderUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableHeaderUI.html) has defaults for `TableHeader.font`, as well as `TableHeader.background` and `TableHeader.foreground`. You can use [`UIManager.put()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) with the `TableHeader.font` key to override the default.