# Change a JTable's Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel

I have a JTable and need to change some of it's properties, such as it's Highlight colour.

[This website](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JTableLookandFeel.htm) indicates there are fields in the table such as "highlight" and "light".

[image]

I can't find them anywhere. When you create an instance of a JTable, nothing involving "Highlight" or "light" show up in intellisense. (However some methods such as table.setFont() do show up).

I did however notice `table.setUI();`  but I don't know how to use it, or if it has anything to do with this.

What I exactly am looking for is to make a row change it's colour when you hover the mouse over it, I'm not sure if `Highlight` will do this or if I will have to go the long way by implementing the mouseListener. I still want to be able to change other L&F settings though.

Comment: See also [Customizing JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209849/customizing-jtable), a possible duplicate of your question.

Comment: @trashgod I'm not interested in changing the header UI, but the actual fields ui, and would like some examples or help on how to do it.

Comment: @StanislavL Could you explain that in a better way and in a proper answer please? Ideally including an example?

Comment: The property strings you cite are keys used to access a map of defaults established by the `UIManager` for a particular Look & Feel.

Comment: Renderer examples may be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the codes below will work because I grabbed and modified it from some chunks of one of my old project's codes, but you could try.

```
public class MyTable extends JTable implements MouseMotionListener {
    int mouseHoverRow = -1;

    public MyTable() {
           addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    //codes

    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex,
            int vColIndex) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, vColIndex);
        Color back = getSelectionBackground();
        int red = back.getRed();
        int green = back.getGreen();
        int blue = back.getBlue();
        if (rowIndex == mouseHoverRow) {
            c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(getBackground());
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        mouseHoverRow = rowAtPoint(p);
    }
```

Comment: Added `table.repaint();` at the end of `mouseMoved()` and made some more modifications to this code and it worked beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably reach your goal by setting one or several properties you cite in the [UIManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) (or the [UIDefaults](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html)) using the method `#put(String, String)` before rendering your JTable.

This link may also help you a bit: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ListUIPropertiesinaJTableandsortable.htm

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried UIManager.put("highlight", Color.red); but it didn't seem to work though. I'll try some other colour values next.

Answer (score 1):

there are four ways

1) override UI

2) use Renderers

- [prepareRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900628/refreshing-background-color-for-a-row-in-jtable/6901508#6901508)
- lots of various examples for [TableCellRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20jtable%20tablecellrenderer)

3) for better and nice output to the GUI I recomending to change [Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java) or use [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) or [Synth Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

4) put all a.m. options together and with Custom painting for [JViewPort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678), `ScrollBar`

Comment: @David confortable would be  look for `prepareRenderer` (works for whole TableView) as for `TableCellRenderer` (valid for particular TableColumn), please carrefully with Opacities for JTable, TableCellRenderer and TableCellEditor (for getTableCellRendererComponent(...) from link that you posted), I'm not sure that Opacity works as I expected, and that's please follows examples from this forum, there are lots of better code and excellent described

Comment: +1 especially for 3) and the good links. It was hard to choose an answer, but I was looking for an SSCCE. I have learnt alot from this though.