# change the style(font, font size, background color) of column name in Jtable, Jframe

Tags: java, colors, jtable, jframe

i want to ask how to change the style(font, background color) of column name in table. i'm using Jtable, Jframe, Java

```
table_test.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "NO", "CODE", "ADDRESS", "CLASS"
        }
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    table_test.setRowHeight(30);
    table_test.setSelectionMode(0);

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table_test);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(55);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(55);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(120);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(120);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(280);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(280);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(63);
    table_test.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(63);
```

This is the image :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it like using table header set font,

```
table.getTableHeader().setFont( ... );
```

Example:

```
table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
```

Comment: Also consider altering the UI defaults, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6222720/230513).